# Calculating a total cost based on how many stripes someone wants on their clothes

Tags: vb.net, math, addition

I'm trying to make it so that if someone wants 3 or less stripes on their shorts it costs 50 cent per stripe on top of the 5.50 base cost for a pair of shorts and then every stripe after the third costs 2 euro each. It works if they chose 3 or less but once I enter any stripe amount above 3 it just displays the base 5.50 cost for the shorts. Not sure what to do any help is appreciated.

I have declared all my variables correctly, I assume the problem is with the code below

```
   'calculate cost of Shorts
    If mskShortStripes.Text <= 3 Then
        dblTotalShorts += CDbl(mskShorts.Text * 5.5) + (mskShortStripes.Text * 0.5)
    ElseIf mskShortStripes.Text > 3 Then
        dblTotalShorts += CDbl(mskShorts.Text * 5.5) + (mskShortStripes.Text <= 3 * 0.5) + (mskShortStripes.Text > 3 * 2)

    End If
```

Comment: Typo or basic math? (`stripes <= 3 * 0.5` vs `(stripes - 3) * 0.5`) :)

Comment: What do you mean? correct me if Im wrong but from what I have coded for example if the user entered 7 stripes, would it not multiply 3 by .5 for the first stripes and then the remaining 4 stripes would be multiplied by 2 and both of those added to whatever the cost of the shorts are for a total cost ? Ive been staring at this for an hour so forgive me if it seems simple i must be going mad

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` on top of your VB file. You have several syntax and converting errors in your code.

Comment: What is result of `stripes <= 3 * 0.5` operation? Plain zero (false equals 0 in VB) for two or more stripes.

Comment: It takes the value entered by the user in the masked text box called mskShortsStripe and then if that value is less than or equal to 3 it multiples it by 50 cent and adds it to the total cost. That part of the code works. For example 2 stripes would be 2 x.5. It just stops working when you have more than 3 stripes

Comment: Ooooooooh . I fully understand what your saying now with the -3 thing. I don’t know how I didn’t realise that hahahana thanks a million man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for trouble working with the `.Text` property directly as if it were a number.  It is not.  Fun things happen when the value in your control is not actually a number.

Use [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) to convert that string to a number:

```
Dim numberOfStripes As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(mskShortStripes.Text, numberOfStripes) Then
    If numberOfStripes >= 0 Then

        ' ... now do some math in here with the "numberOfStripes" variable ...

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Number of Stripes can't be negative!")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number of Stripes!")
End If
```